# Correct form long time query executing myodbc syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

I'm trying to build one SQL query for Access that links tables with myodbc connection to retrive the data from internet, but the time to finish the query is too long about five minutes, so I think the problem is with the query:

```
SELECT COUNT([o].[orders_id]) AS howmany_orders, 
       (SELECT SUM([op1].[products_quantity]) FROM orders_total AS ot1, orders AS o1, orders_products AS op1
        WHERE [o1].[date_purchased] >=date()-30 and [o1].[orders_id] = [op1].[orders_id] and [ot1].[orders_id] = [op1].[orders_id] and [ot1].[class]="ot_total" and [o1].[orders_status] = 1 and [op1].[products_id]=[op].[products_id]
        GROUP BY [op1].[products_id]
        ) AS pendiente,
        [op].[products_model], 
        Round((((7+1)*(howmany_orders/90))+1)-(p.stock_real- IIF(pendiente>0,pendiente,0)), 0) AS pedir,
        p.ref_id

FROM orders_total AS ot, orders AS o, orders_products AS op INNER JOIN Productos AS p ON Mid([op].[products_model],4) LIKE p.ref_id

WHERE [o].[date_purchased] >=date()-90 and [o].[orders_id] = [op].[orders_id] and [ot].[orders_id] = [op].[orders_id] and [ot].[class]="ot_total" and [o].[orders_status] IN (7, 1) and ((p.fuera_de_stock)=False) and ((p.suspendido)=False) and  ((p.quitar_de_la_web)=False)

GROUP BY [op].[products_model], p.ref_id, p.stock_real, [op].[products_id];
```

At a glance I see that the "**LIKE**" operator could be one of the problems  here:

```
 INNER JOIN Productos AS p ON Mid([op].[products_model],4) LIKE p.ref_id
```

but  I have not way to substitute for an ***=*** operator

Thanks for your help!

EDITING:
I have reduced the query to that but is the same time:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.orders_id) AS howmany_orders, (
SELECT SUM(opz.products_quantity) FROM orders AS oz, orders_products AS opz WHERE oz.date_purchased >=date()-30 and oz.orders_id = opz.orders_id and oz.orders_status = 1 and opz.products_id=op.products_id GROUP BY opz.products_id
) AS pendiente, op.products_model, Round((((7+1)*(howmany_orders/90))+1)-(p.stock_real-IIf(pendiente>0,pendiente,0)),0) AS pedir, p.ref_id
FROM orders AS o, orders_products AS op INNER JOIN Productos AS p ON op.products_model=p.cod
WHERE o.date_purchased>=date()-90 And o.orders_id=op.orders_id And o.orders_status In (7,1) And ((p.suspendido)=False) And ((p.quitar_de_la_web)=False)
GROUP BY op.products_model, p.ref_id, p.stock_real, op.products_id;
```

Comment: The Round() could also be slowing things down, but it will be executed only for the rows returned from the server by the other conditions. That is, the Jet/ACE query optimizer will probably process that Round() last because of the fact that it's in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Joining on a partial match means you've got denormalized data. That is, the first four characters of [products_model] should be a separate field.

Comment: The round doesn't matter ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep there’s your problem. The database can not do the join using any indexes so it has to do a table scan. Is there anyway you could persist this data so you don’t have to do the MID statement and just join on that? i.e. in your products_model table have an extra column with the MID data stored in there with the join on that column

Comment: The problem is that [op].[products_model] is varchar(12) and in access it's a number type cell, anyway I have only numbers in [op].[products_model] but I can't change to int because it's a table of script that has relation with others

Comment: I have added a new field to the database with the MID statment and now is ON [op].[products_model] = p.cod  but the time is being equal long

Comment: Try removing the Round() temporarily. That's going to have an impact, too (though it shouldn't be nearly as great).

Comment: I have added an index for the new field and is the same time aprox. Also delete the round temporarily and the same. The problem is the select inside the select because each one is fast

Comment: ahhh the rows returned are about 70-100 so I don't think this is the problem because the second select